# fluent and webhdfs filename with 197001011

Tags: fluent, fluentd, webhdfs

I run td-agent on ubuntu 14.04 with the follow configuration:

```
    <source>
     type tail
     format json
     path /path/tomcat/logs/file-input.log
     tag bhc.hdfs
     pos_file /var/td-agent/file.pos
     </source>

    <match bhc.hdfs>
     type webhdfs
     port 50070
     host my.host.name
     path /hdfs/path/file.${hostname}.%Y%m%d.log
     username user
     flush_interval 10s
     output_include_time false
     output_include_tag false
     output_data_type json
    </match>
```

Log source files in directory */path/tomcat/logs/file-input.log* contain only a structured json data.
Ntp daemon is installed and running but when td-agent creates file in hdfs date on filename is 19700101.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluentd records has time, and webhdfs plugin creates files with that records' timestamp, not current time.

`tail` plugin uses field named as `time` for time of record in default. If your log data have any other time information field, you can specify it with `time_key` and `time_format`.

See also: http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_tail

Comment: Thanks @Satoshi, but why it's necessary to configure ntp daemon?

Comment: @critical NTP daemon is just for getting right time from server's clock.